# How can I replace a particular column in a data frame based on a condition (categorical variables)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace the salary status to `1` or `0` respectively if the salary is `greater than 50,000` or `less than or equal to 50,000` in a df.

[image: Here is the df:]

The DataFrame shape:30162*13

I have tried this:

```
data2['SalStat']=data2['SalStat'].map({"less than or equal to 50,000":0,"greater than 50,000":1})
```

I also tried `data2['SalStat']`
and `loc` without any success.

How can I do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is nice.

If want match only by substring, e.g. by `greater` use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for boolean mask with converting to `0,1`:

```
data2['SalStat']=data2['SalStat'].str.contains('greater').astype(int)
```

Or:

```
data2['SalStat']=data2['SalStat'].str.contains('greater').view('i1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def status(d): return 0 if d == 'less than or equal to 50,000' else 1
data2['SalStat']  = list(map(status ,data2['SalStat']))
```